# ADB not finding infinix X506 Android phone after driver installation on win7

Tags: android, usb, adb, driver

I have just started android native development and going good. However, I cannot test my android apps on my Infinix X506 (a.k.a Infinix Zero) as it is not found by ADB. I have the driver for the phone up to date on my computer and tried a number of manual installation options but Win7 keeps saying driver is already up to date.

I borrowed a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 from a friend and installed the driver and this worked at once. ADB found it and I can deploy apps to it.

Is there anyone that has used an Infinix phone for development like this or that can point to what I am missing.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/11/adb-device-detection-in-windows.html

Answer (score -1):

make a try with Universal ADB Driver

http://www.koushikdutta.com/post/universal-adb-driver